# Hbase: Scan with column filter(Get rows which does have a particular column)

Tags: hbase

I am trying to fetch rows using scan . I need those rows where a particular column is not present.
I have tried multiple approaches but none seems to be working.

Let say I want rows where column "fs" is not present.
I have tried the below:-

```
SingleColumnValueFilter filter1 = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
                       "f".getBytes(),
                       Bytes.toBytes("fs"),
                       CompareOp.NOT_EQUAL,
                       Bytes.toBytes(1)
                       );
```

Assuming if "fs" is present it will have value 1.

This does not work.
Also tried what is mentioned here
[How can I skip HBase rows that are missing specific columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879218/how-can-i-skip-hbase-rows-that-are-missing-specific-columns) but that too din worked.

Comment: suggestion with SkipFilter was wrong, it filters entire row if any cell does not match filter condition. I guess your rows with 'fs' column have some other columns too and get filtered.

Comment: Yes they have other columns as well

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion with [SkipFilter](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SkipFilter.html) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31360071/1289981) is not wrong but not applicable for your case (as @AdamSkywalker pointed out).

But you can create two separate [SkipFilters](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SkipFilter.html) on top of [ColumnRangeFilters](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/ColumnRangeFilter.html) for ranges ["0", "fs") and ("fs", "z"]. And these filters should be combined with [FilterList](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterList.html) and [MUST_PASS_ONE](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterList.Operator.html) FilterList's combination rule.

Example code which can be tested in HBase shell:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.ColumnRangeFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SkipFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.FilterList
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.FilterList.Operator
scan 'table', {FILTER => FilterList.new(FilterList::Operator::MUST_PASS_ONE,SkipFilter.new(ColumnRangeFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes("0"), true, Bytes.toBytes("fs"), false)),SkipFilter.new(ColumnRangeFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes("fs"), false, Bytes.toBytes("z"), true)))}
```

In Java API code your filter should look like that:

```
SkipFilter range1 = new SkipFilter(new ColumnRangeFilter(Bytes.toBytes("0"), true, Bytes.toBytes("fs"), false));
SkipFilter range2 = new SkipFilter(new ColumnRangeFilter(Bytes.toBytes("fs"), false, Bytes.toBytes("z"), true))
FilterList filter = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE, range1, range2)
```

Note that in this example column name range is limited to printable symbols only. If you use byte arrays as column names you should define wider range.